# XSL. To display text according format specified in data text

Tags: xslt

Sorry for my English.

I wrote XML sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="./test.xslt"?>
<document>
  <paragraph id="p1">
    I like &lt;i&gt;the flowers&lt;/i&gt;!!!
  </paragraph>
  <paragraph id="p2">
    <![CDATA[I like <i>the people</i>!!!]]>
  </paragraph>
</document>
```

And I wrote XSL for it sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <p>
          <xsl:value-of select="/document/paragraph[@id='p1']"/>
          <br/>
          <xsl:value-of select="/document/paragraph[@id='p2']"/>
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I specified formatting in text values (<i>some text</i>). But formatting not happens. I get next result in the browser:

```
I like <i>the flowers</i>!!! 
I like <i>the people</i>!!!
```

How to force to apply the specified formatting?

Regards

Comment: Not clear... Exactly what is not happening that you expected and how did you specify your formatting?

Comment: Oh, I found the response... 
`code <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
   <body>
  <p>
    <xsl:value-of select="/document/paragraph[@id='p1']" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    <br/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/document/paragraph[@id='p2']" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </p>
   </body>
 </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: The parameter 'disable-output-escaping="yes"' solved this problem

Comment: @Bush Exactly. You should write that as an answer to your own question instead of a comment.

Comment: I can not. I get message: "Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 5 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Comment: @Bush: Try to avoid DOE. It isn't supported by all XSLT 1.0 processors -- for example the one used by FF doesn't support DOE. XSLT 2.0 and up don't have DOE as part of the language at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is a frequently asked question.

**Destroyed markup (such as serialized to escaped string representation) is dispalyed by the browser as text** -- this is exactly how escaped characters should be interpreted).

In order to achieve the desired formatting, don't destroy the markup.

Instead of:

```
I like &lt;i&gt;the flowers&lt;/i&gt;!!!
```

use:

```
I like <i>the flowers<i>!!!
```

Also, replace:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="/document/paragraph[@id='p1']"/>
```

with:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/document/paragraph[@id='p1']/node()"/>
```

**To summarize:**

**Use this XML document**:

```
<document>
    <paragraph id="p1">
      I like <i>the flowers</i>!!!
  </paragraph>
    <paragraph id="p2">I like <i>the people</i>!!!</paragraph>
</document>
```

**and change the transformation to this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="html"/>
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
          <body>
            <p>
              <xsl:copy-of select="/document/paragraph[@id='p1']/node()"/>
              <br/>
              <xsl:copy-of select="/document/paragraph[@id='p2']/node()"/>
            </p>
          </body>
        </html>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p>
              I like <i>the flowers</i>!!!
           <br>I like <i>the people</i>!!!
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

**and it displays in the browser like this**:

I like *the flowers*!!!
           
I like *the people*!!!

Comment: While this is true, it only works as long as the contents of `<paragraph>` is well-formed XML. It might be a fragment of HTML though, which would require CDATA or XML-encoding, which in turn would make `disable-output-escaping` necessary.

Comment: @Tomalak: DOE isn't in XSLT starting from 2.0 and up. Even in XSLT 1.0 DOE isn't a mandatory feature and some XSLT 1.0 processors don't implement it. DOE stands against the architectural model of XSLT and thus is best avoided. In case someone wants to process with XSLT an instance of HTML that isn't well-formed XML, they can always use a tydying preprocessing step (quite a number of existing systems do this conveniently), or an extension parsing function that transforms non-well-formed HTML fragments into well-formed XML fragments.

Comment: That's right. DOE is not *clean*, but when the XSLT processor provides the feature, why not use it? It's a quick-win solution for the given problem. Inserting a step that sanitizes the HTML contents to be XML compliant is possible, but has its drawbacks. HTML5 is not exactly XML, for example. It may contain named entity references unknown to XML. Of course there are ways to deal with this, but the pragmatic approach isn't the worst alternative.

Comment: @Tomalak: Today's developers write client-side XSLT transformations and want these to be successfully processed regardless of the browser that's used. Impossible, if they use DOE.

Comment: I've noticed that tendency. I have never cared much for client-side transformations. The level of client-side XSLT support is just as unpredictable and divergent as the kinds of possible target platforms. I tend to think server-side by default and I still think that's the more reasonable approach.

Comment: @Tomalak: In fact there are JQuery plugins that allow client-side XSLT 1.0 processing independent on the browser platform: http://johannburkard.de/software/xsltjs/ Also, SaxonCE (http://www.saxonica.com/ce/doc/contents.html) provides browser-independent, clientside XSLT 2.0 support.

Comment: Yes, but when it comes to that kind of work I think I'd rather use JSON and a HTML templating engine instead of XSLT.

Comment: @Tomalak: One could use either. XSLT 3.0 could provide support for parsing and processing JSON (let's wait for the next WD). This, added to the strong typing in XSLT 2.0 and above, makes XSLT a more robust, higher quality choice of client-side processing language.

Comment: The abundance of JavaScript will make this pretty tough. Especially since XSLT will not be able to interact with the DOM.

Comment: @Tomalak: Our discussion is technical -- not political. There is XSLT 2.0 available client-side for all browsers. There is XQuery available client-side for all browsers. We need to wait and witness their adoption. Reminds me of the days when they used "electricity for light" and were sceptical on the use of the "mechanical horses" for transportation :)

Comment: Thanks for answers. What is 'DOE'?

Comment: @Bush: DOE = disable-output-escaping

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to me to understand the discussion which is present above in comments since I badly understand English language and still feebly I understand in XSL. The option with use ''disable-output-escaping="yes"'' for me seems the simply and convenient. The option with 'xsl:copy-of' too is interesting to me and I am grateful for it.

Comment: Bush, The discussion about DOE treats exactly the topic why it is wise *not* to use DOE (disable-output-escaping).